# Linux virtual keyboard and evdev

Tags: linux, input, udev, evdev

I write some software for Linux, which uses libevdev for input processing.

To my surprise all virtual onscreen keyboards that I found simulate high level X Window Server events. So, they're not recognized by udev, don't appear at /dev/input folder and aren't visible with evtest.

Is there any software keyboard that is low-level enough for that? Or maybe some trick for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good reason why this is done in this way. The /dev/input devices are devices that have somekind of physical (electrical, optical and/or mechanical) input. These are converted by the linux kernel drive into something that generates EV_EVENTS. These events are processed by the xf86_input_evdev driver in to X11 inputs, which are understood by the server. As you can generate X11 inputs from an X11 program, it is quite a lot of work to create a device driver that accepts input on one side from an X11 app and generates input on the other. So while not impossible, it is a lot of work for no gain to create a driver or two for this purpose.